# How to wrap useSWR hook and get correct response type infer?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to wrap `useSWR` like below but I can't get the correct response type inferring by the fetcher as same way I get correctly when I just use `useSWR`

```
const useMySWR = (...args: Parameters<typeof useSWR>) => {
  return useSWR(args);
};
```

When I wrap, the type inferring of the fetcher doesn't seem working. I face similar problem in some cases, can someone give me an insight?

Answer (score 0):

```
const useMySWR: typeof useSWR = <T>(...args: T[]) => {
  return useSWR(args);
};
```

this seems the right way